# MissingResourceException running MXJ for MySQL

Tags: java, mysql, database, jdbc

I'm using the code from [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.0/en/connector-mxj-configuration-java-object.html) tutorial for using MXJ to "embed" MySQL in my java application.  However, I'm getting this exception when running the code:

```
Exception in thread "main" java.util.MissingResourceException: Resource '5-5-9/Windows_7-amd64/mysqld.exe' not found
```

This happens when I reach this line in the tutorial:

```
mysqldResource.start("test-mysqld-thread", database_options);
```

I'm running in Eclipse and I have the 4 following jars added to my build path, since [this](http://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.1/en/connector-mxj-install-base.html) link says I need them:

```
mysql-connector-java-5.1.18-bin.jar
mysql-connector-mxj-gpl-5-0-12-db-files.jar
mysql-connector-mxj-gpl-5-0-12.jar
aspectjrt-1.6.9.jar
```

I'm not sure what I'm missing here.  Any tips?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Actually it's never a good idea to mess up with the jar files, cause whenever you upgrade to a newer version you'll need to remember to redo this fix again. The answer is correct, but you just need to create platform-map.properties file with this inside:

```
Windows_7-amd64=Win-x86
```

and add it to your classpath.

Comment: what reads that platform-map.properties file?  where is that documented?

Answer (score 6):

MXJ doesn't come ready for use with Windows 7 64 bit.  Using [this](http://bugs.mysql.com/bug.php?id=48298) bug ticket, I found what I needed to do.

Once the files are downloaded and extracted from the zips, unjar `mysql-connector-mxj-gpl-5-0-12-db-files.jar` and add a line to platform-map.properties file inside:

```
Windows_7-amd64=Win-x86
```

Save, and re-jar.  Works like a charm!

Answer (score 0):

For anyone who has the same issue on MacOS Catalina, you can follow the README.md in my repo (https://github.com/pengyue/mysql-connector-mxj-mac-os-catalina), which has the 64 bits executables for MacOS Catalina, and this improved connector works on Catalina.

To explain what I have done:

- Download the 64 bits executables from MySQL to the folder `5-5-9`
- Add the platform mapping for 64 bits MacOS in `platform-map.properties`
- Create a jar by using `jar cvf mysql-connector-mxj-db-files-5.0.12.jar .`
- Replace the jar in your mvn settings folder `~/.m2/repository/mysql/mysql-connector-mxj-db-files/5.0.12/` with the jar you just created.

This solution works fine for my projects, Unfortunately I could not find a github for the mysql-connector-mxj, as it is deprecated and not maintainable anymore.

The other option is to use wix-embedded-mysql(https://github.com/wix/wix-embedded-mysql) instead of mysql-connector-mxj, but this probably requires some code changes in your projects.

Comment: Welcome to the community. it would be nice if you show us a chunck of the solution.

Comment: Welcome new user. Instead of linking to a solution, it's usually better to include the information on the page you're linking to in your answer. A good rule of thumb is your post should still answer the question even if that page you are linking to changes or disappears years from now.

Comment: While this link may answer the question, it is better to include the essential parts of the answer here and provide the link for reference.  Link-only answers can become invalid if the linked page changes. - [From Review](/review/low-quality-posts/25346976)

Comment: @PetarTonev I have explained how to fix it with the bullet points in my answer.